# Need help finding a closed form for complicated sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form expression for the following sequence:

$$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(n-1-i+d)!}{(n-2i)!(i)!}=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{(n-1-i+d)!}{(n-2i)!(i)!}$$

Where $n$ and $d$ are both positive integers.

An important note!: I'm actually not even interested in an exact solution. Any closed form that is a 'reasonably' close approximation is fine!

Now I have no reason to assume a close form even exists, and the expression looks quite ugly, so I would even go as far as to say that I highly doubt a closed form exists, but maybe someone can take a look and tell why it does/does not exist.

Thanks!

Edit: an other way to write the sequence is as:

$$a_n=(d-1)!\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n-1-i+d}{n-2i}\binom{i+d-1}{i}$$

Maybe someone will recognize this or know how to deal with this.

Comment: Do you realize that you have factorials of negative integers in the denominator?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Which is not a problem. It just makes the notation cleaner.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott see edit. Maybe you like the second form better, but I though the first one was more clear

Comment: @user2520938 thanks for clarification

Comment: @Pp..: In the absence of an explicitly stated convention I consider it a problem. It could also have been a genuine oversight, which is why I asked.

Comment: @user2520938: I much prefer the second; the first is genuinely confusing. (I myself would go further and use the exact upper limit, but I can live with $n/2$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The first thing the experts do in A=B is to drop the limits. Not $n/2$, not $n$, not $i=1$, but $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$. They are irrelevant in this kind of problems.

Comment: I find $\sum_{n=1}^n$ impossible to interpret. Is it $i$ you are summing over? Also starting the summation at $1$ is almost never what one wants; should it be $0$?

Comment: @FelixMarin What do you mean about the last term not being true?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. I guess I was confused with the binomial. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with [Gegenbauer polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials) ? Either way, we can use [their definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GegenbauerPolynomial.html)

in rewriting the sum as $a_n=\pi\cdot\big(-{\bf i}\big)^n\cdot{\large\bf C}_n^{(d)}\bigg(\dfrac{\bf i}2\bigg)\cdot\displaystyle\lim_{\delta\to d}\dfrac{\csc\big(\delta\pi\big)}{\big(-\delta\big)!}$ , where the limit can

be evaluated using Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) as $\dfrac{\Gamma\big(d\big)}\pi=\dfrac{\big(d-1\big)!}\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Im not familiar with any of the things you said, but i will try figuring it out.

Comment: Could it be that it should be $i^n$ instead of $(-i)^n$? And this is an approximation right? (which is perfectly fine by the way)

Comment: No, it is an exact closed form. The $(-1)^n$ comes from $\csc\Big((n+\delta)\pi\Big)$. The $i^n$ is meant to transform the Gegenbauer polynomial of imaginary argument into a real value.

Comment: But evaluation of the value at $d=2$ gives the following list of values with $n=1,...,10$ and $(-i)^n$: {-2, 5, -10, 20, -38, 71, -130, 235, -420, 744}, while $i^n$ gives {2, 5, 10, 20, 38, 71, 130, 235, 420, 744}.

Comment: Also, the same values according to the original definition are: {0, 2, 6, 15, 32, 64, 122, 226, 410, 733}, which is close but not exact.

Comment: You're right. My sum started at $i=0$, so you must subtract the first term, namely $\dfrac{(n+d-1)!}{n!}$

Comment: Ah oke. Yea now it seems to be exact. Do you think there's any chance of a simpler expression existing? And do you think this expression is usable if I need start summing it and do more manipulation with it. Or will I just end up with equally unworkable expressions as the one I started with?

Comment: Given the fact that, by their very definition, Gegenbauer polynomials are a part of the general term of an infinite series, whose value is a rational function, it might be possible $($though I can't be sure$)$ for such a sum to yield a closed form result.

Comment: Oke. Well I'll give it a couple more days to see if maybe someone else comes along and gives a different solution, and then I'll accept your answer. Thanks again

Comment: ...or you might try to put it up for a bounty, to draw more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we can simplify the problem a wee bit and change the lower limit in the sum to zero. Thus we have:
\begin{equation}
F_n:= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(n-1+k+d)!}{k!(n-2 k)!}
\end{equation}

Now, by using either Sister Celine's or the Zeilberger algorithms we quickly establish the recursion relation satisfied by the quantity in question: It reads:
\begin{equation}
F_n = \frac{1}{n} \left[ (n+d-1) F_{n-1} + (n+2 d-2) F_{n-2}\right]
\end{equation}
for $n\ge 2$.

Now, we define the generating function $F(x) := \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty F_n x^n$. This function satisfies the following differential equation:

\begin{equation}
(1-x-x^2)F^{'}(x) = d(1+2 x) F(x) + (F_1-d F_0)
\end{equation}
where $F(0)=F_0$ and $F^{'}(0)=F_1$.
The solution to the differential equation reads:
\begin{equation}
F(x) = (F_1-d \cdot F_0) \cdot \frac{\sum\limits_{0\le l_1 \le l \le d-1} \binom{d-1}{l} \binom{l}{l_1} (-1)^l \frac{x^{l+l_1+1}}{(l+l_1+1)}}{(1-x-x^2)^d} + \frac{F_0}{(1-x-x^2)^d}
\end{equation}

The solution above has a following partial fraction decomposition:
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^d \left[ \frac{A_+^{(d)}(j)}{(2 x+1+\sqrt{5})^j} + \frac{A_-^{(d)}(j)}{(2 x+1-\sqrt{5})^j}\right]
\end{equation}
where the numbers $\left( A_\pm^{(d)}(j)\right)_{j=1}^d$ are linear combinations of $F_0$ and $F_0$ only with coefficients belonging to ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5})$.
Finally, the closed form solution to the sum in question reads:
\begin{equation}
F_n = \sum\limits_{j=1}^d  \frac{(-2)^n j^{(n)}}{n!} \cdot \left( \frac{A_+^{(d)}(j)}{(1+\sqrt{5})^{j+n}} + \frac{A_-^{(d)}(j)}{(1-\sqrt{5})^{j+n}}\right)
\end{equation}