# What techniques does Mathematica use to find solutions to these sequences?

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

This question is related to my previous question: [Need help finding a closed form for complicated sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096328/need-help-finding-a-closed-form-for-complicated-sum).

An answer to that question led my to try and find the general term of the following recurrence:

$$t_n=(-i)^nr_n$$
Where

$$r_n=\frac{1}{n}(i(n+d-1)r_{n-1}-(n+2d-2)r_{n-2})$$
And $d$ is some positive integer.

Now this might look terrible, and it is, but somehow Mathematica manages to find closed forms for sequences for specific values of $d$.

So for example, if $d=1$, a closed form for this sequence $t_n$ is this:
$$t_{d=1}(n)=F_n$$

Where $F_n$ is the $n$th fibonacci number. However, for $d=2$ things become a lot more complicated:

$$t_{d=2}(n)=-\frac{(2^{-n}(2(365 + 163\sqrt5)((1-\sqrt5)^n-(1+\sqrt[5])^n)+
    5((1-\sqrt5)^n(101+45\sqrt5)-2(1+\sqrt5)^n(132+59\sqrt[5])) n)}{25(163+73\sqrt5))}$$

In which some traces of the fibonacci sequence can still be recognised, but it is not clear exactly how this solution came to be (at least not to me).

Now the thing is, that Mathematica can generate an expression like this for every $d$. However, when I try to make it solve the 'general' case with $d$ as some variable, it cannot do it.

This general closed form solution is of course what I'm interested in. I am (again), not at all sure that such a general closed form in terms of $n$ and $d$ exists, but I would really like to try and find one.

However, I have no idea how Mathematica finds those closed forms for specific values of $d$, and I feel like knowing what it is doing might help me figure out way to tackle this problem.

So does some one have an idea of what kind of techniques can be used (maybe also other techniques than just those used by Mathematica) to find solutions to this recurrence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The technique being used is the method of generating functions. Define 
\begin{equation}
r(x):= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty r_n x^n
\end{equation}
It is not hard to see that the quantity above obeys a following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
(x- i \cdot x^2+x^3) \frac{d r(x)}{d x} = (i \cdot d \cdot x - 2 d \cdot x^2) r(x)- i \cdot d \cdot r_0 x 
\end{equation}
This is a linear , in-homogeneous  first order differential equation and as such can always be solved in terms of elementary functions for every $i \in {\mathbb N}$ and $d\in {\mathbb N}$. Having obtained the solution all one needs to do is to compute the $n$ th derivative at $x=0$ and divide the result by $n!$. This also can be always done because as it turns out the solutions are always rational functions.

Below, I paste a snippet of Mathematica code that finds a closed form solution for the sequence $\left( r_n\right)_{n=0}^\infty$.

```
i = 3; d = 2; Clear[r]; x =.; MM = 20; r0 =.;
rr[x_] = First[
   r[x] /. DSolve[{(x - i x^2 + x^3) r'[x] == (i d x - 2 d x^2) r[x] -
         i d r0 x, r[0] == r0}, r[x], x]];
ext = x /. Solve[Denominator[rr[x]] == 0, x];
dd = Factor[Denominator[rr[x]], Extension -> ext];
ss = Apart[Numerator[rr[x]]/dd, x]
FullSimplify[ss - rr[x]]
n =.;
f[n_] = ss /. 
  CC_ (A_. x + B_)^nu_ :> 
   CC A^nu 1/n! Pochhammer[nu - n + 1, n] (B/A)^(nu - n)

rrr = Simplify[Table[f[n], {n, 0, MM}]]
Table[rrr[[1 + n]] - 
  1/n (i (n + d - 1) rrr[[n]] - (n + 2 d - 2) rrr[[n - 1]]), {n, 2, 
  MM}]
```

Running the code for $i=3$ and $d=2$ produces the following output:

```
(2^(1 + n) (-3 - Sqrt[5])^(-2 - 
   n) (11 + 5 Sqrt[5]) r0 Pochhammer[-1 - n, n])/(5 n!) - (
 2^(1 + n) (-3 + Sqrt[5])^(-2 - 
   n) (-11 r0 + 5 Sqrt[5] r0) Pochhammer[-1 - n, n])/(
 5 n!) - ((1/2 (-3 - Sqrt[5]))^(-1 - 
   n) (11 + 5 Sqrt[5]) r0 Pochhammer[-n, n])/(
 5 Sqrt[5] n!) + ((1/2 (-3 + Sqrt[5]))^(-1 - 
   n) (-25 + 11 Sqrt[5]) r0 Pochhammer[-n, n])/(25 n!)

{r0, 0, -2 r0, -8 r0, -27 r0, -86 r0, -265 r0, -798 r0, -2362 r0, \
-6898 r0, -19929 r0, -57070 r0, -162227 r0, -458268 r0, -1287602 r0, \
-3600956 r0, -10029495 r0, -27833798 r0, -76996477 r0, -212383098 r0, \
-584310634 r0}

{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Here the top line is the closed form expression for the sequence $\left( r_n\right)_{n=0}^\infty$ , the line underneath shows the first twenty values of the sequence and the bottom line is a verification that the sequence indeed satisfies the recurrence relation.

Note, that one does not need to use Mathematica to produce those closed form solutions since all the analytical techniques are known. It is just handy to use this CAS because the expressions in questions are pretty big and hard to handle by hand.

Note2: As a matter of fact the solution here is only a particular one since it assumes that $r_1=0$.

Update: Here I only note that the solution to the differential equation in the text above reads:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&r(x)=-i \cdot d \cdot r_0\frac{\sum\limits_{0\le l_1 \le l \le d-1} \binom{d-1}{l} \binom{l}{l_1} (-i)^{l-l_1} \frac{x^{l+l_1+1}}{l+l_1+1}}{(1-i \cdot x+x^2)^d} + \frac{r_0}{(1-i\cdot x+x^2)^d}\\
&&=r_0\cdot\sum\limits_{j=1}^d C^{(d)}_j 
\left( \frac{\sum\limits_{l=0}^d i^{2 l} \left( a^{(d)}_l \cdot i + \sqrt{i^2-4} \cdot b^{(d)}_l\right)}{(i^2-4)^{d-(j-1)/2}}\cdot \frac{1}{(x-x_+)^j} + (-1)^{d+j+1-\xi}\frac{\sum\limits_{l=0}^d i^{2 l} \left( a^{(d)}_l \cdot i - \sqrt{i^2-4} \cdot b^{(d)}_l\right)}{(i^2-4)^{d-(j-1)/2}}\cdot \frac{1}{(x-x_-)^j}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\xi:=d\%2$ and $x_\pm:=1/2(i\pm \sqrt{i^2-4})$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(a^{(d)}_l\right)_{d=1,l=0}^{6,d}&=&\{\{4,-1\},\{-16,8,-1\},\{64,-48,12,-1\},\{-256,256,-96,16,-1\},\{1024,-1280,640,-160,20,-1\},\{-4096,6144,-3840,1280,-240,24,-1\}\}\\
\left(b^{(d)}_l\right)_{d=1,l=0}^{6,d}&=&\{\{-2,1\},\{6,-6,1\},\{-20,30,-10,1\},\{70,-140,70,-14,1\},\{-252,630,-420,126,-18,1\},\{924,-2772,2310,-924,198,-22,1\}\}\\
\left(C^{(d)}_j\right)_{d=1,j=1}^{6,d}&=&\left\{\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\},\left\{\frac{2}{6},\frac{2}{12}\right\},\left\{\frac{3}{10},\frac{3}{20},\frac{3}{60}\right\},\left\{\frac{4}{14},\frac{4}{28},\frac{4}{70},\frac{4}{280}\right\},\left\{\frac{5}{18},\frac{5}
   {36},\frac{5}{84},\frac{5}{252},\frac{5}{1260}\right\},\left\{\frac{6}{22},\frac{6}{44},\frac{6}{99},\frac{6}{264},\frac{6}{924},\frac{6}{5544}\right\}\right\}
\end{eqnarray}
Now, the solution to the original recurrence relation is obtained from the bottom-most equation above by inverting the Z-transform, meaning by the substitution below:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(x-x_\pm)^j} \longrightarrow \binom{j+n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{(-x_\pm)^{j+n}}
\end{equation}